# django rest framework modelserializer is_valid return false when declare custom field with source attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was working on some project which read data from rest API then deserialize data for storing into database. Below are model and deserializer

```
class ExchangeInfo(models.Model):
    server_time = models.BigIntegerField()
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ExchangeInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    server_time = serializers.IntegerField(source='serverTime')
    timezone = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)


    class Meta:
        model = ExchangeInfo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Below is the code I used to deserialize data

```
def load_exchange_info():
    exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
    from common.models import ExchangeInfo
    from common.serializers import ExchangeInfoSerializer
    exchange_info_serializer = ExchangeInfoSerializer(data=exchange_info)
    exchange_info_serializer.is_valid()
    print(exchange_info_serializer.errors)
```

Some how the is_valid always return False with the error below.

```
{'server_time': ['This field is required.']}
```

Any suggestion on what the issue is?

**Edit**:

The correct serializer is:

```
class ExchangeInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serverTime = serializers.IntegerField(source='server_time')
    timezone = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = ExchangeInfo
        fields = ('serverTime', 'timezone')
```

Comment: so you data doesnt have servertime

Comment: After 1 hour debugging, I found the correct way to do it. See my edit.